# How to not make a progressbar crash when it exceeds it's max value

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I got a question about the progressbar.

I am making a game on Windows forms application. I got a progressbar that is used to show the current "power". In my case it works like this:

Everytime player1 attacks. The AI attacks back and get 100 power. WHen it comes to 400 power a new damage comes in. Everything works quite well. but when I press the attack button again.. the max value of 400 will be exceeded and the program shuts because of an error.

So my question is. How to set the max value to a progressbar and make it not crash? is there any method for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: bar.Value = Math.Min(someValue, bar.Maximum);

Comment: put some codes and errors plz

Comment: Thanks for reply. Did not work for me tough. I have tried something else. It does not win the beauty price but it works now :P

Comment: _Did not work for me though._ How would that not work?? Of course you may need to add the checks for the Minimum value: `bar.Value = Math.Max( Math.Min(someValue, bar.Maximum) , bar.Minimum); ` - Resetting to zero or hiding and displaying a completion message is a different problem and the best solution will depend on the rest of the application. Don't make it too fast or else the user will not even know it has finished..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to awnser my own question.

The result is working. But it does not win the beauty price in programming.

Here is the code for everything about the progress bar:

```
    public void ProgressBarVegeta()
    {
        ProgressPowerVijand1.Value = (int)(vijand1.opladen());
        ProgressPowerVijand1.Maximum = 400;
        if (ProgressPowerVijand1.Value == 400)
        {
            ProgressBarHide();
        }
        //ProgressPowerVijand1.Value = Math.Min(0, ProgressPowerVijand1.Maximum);
    }

    public void ProgressBarHide()
    {
        ProgressPowerVijand1.Hide();
    }
```

This code is from the character class:

```
class Vijand1
{

    public double opladen()
    {
        opladenVijand1 = opladenVijand1 + 100;

        if( opladenVijand1 == 500)
        {
            opladenVijand1 = 0;
        }
        return opladenVijand1;
    }
```

With this code it resets the progress bar whenever it (was) going to crash. So with this code it reset and hides the progressbar. Else I would see the green bar that resets itself at 400 everytime

Comment: If you find the answer so mark your answer so other people may have this same problem will get the answer.